# html5 vs jquery drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm starting the development of a webapp, I want to use HTML5 as much as I can. My application has an interface with a heavy use of drag and drop, my question is, at this moment, is it recommended to use the html5 native drag and drop? or is it better to use another js library for that like jquery ui?

Thanks in advance

Escobar

Answer (score 21, accepted):

HTML 5 is widely considered the next major step in web development and many browsers have begun the adoption of the new standard. So think of using HTML 5 to accomplish these tasks as an investment in future technologies. It will make your application more robust and more scalable.

Unfortunately HTML5 is still new and many browsers don't support (parts of) it. I suggest using HTML 5 and having the ability to fallback to Javascript if the browser doesn't support the feature.

Using [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) you can easily detect the feature like so

```
if(Modernizr.draganddrop) {
   // HTML 5!
} else {
   // Javascript fallback option
}
```

Comment: Sounds tedious, you need to maintain 2 codes afterwards, no?