# Prevent drag event to interfere with input elements in Firefox using HTML5 drag/drop

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

It seems that an input element loses a lot of functionality when put into an element with draggable="true". This only seems to occur in firefox.

See my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/WC9Fe/3/

Html:

```
<div id="drag" draggable="true">
    Drag this div <br />
    <input id="message" type="text" />
</div>
<div id="drop">
    Drop area
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#drag').on('dragstart', function(e){
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('Text', $('#message').val());
    e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
});

var drop = $('#drop');
drop.on('dragover', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
drop.on('dragenter', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
drop.on('drop', function(e){
    alert('Target succesfully dropped: ' + e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text'));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Now try to select text in the input using firefox. Seems impossible. Try the same in IE/Chrome. Seems to work just fine.

Comment: This issue is also observed in IE... IE 11.0.9600 to be precise..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As far as I know this is a known bug in FF. A quick (and "*dirty*" workaround) would be to remove the `draggable` attribute on text input `focus` event, add it again on text input `blur` event, and disable text selection on #drag div to enable dragging once you clicked outside the focused input (clicking on #div directly).

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WC9Fe/8/).

Sample code:

JS:

```
$('#message')
    .on('focus', function(e) {
        $(this).closest('#drag').attr("draggable", false);
    })
    .on('blur', function(e) {
        $(this).closest('#drag').attr("draggable", true);
    });
```

CSS:

```
.disable-selection {
    /* event if these are not necessary, let's just add them */
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

    /* this will add drag availability once you clicked the 
       #drag div while you're focusing #message div */
    -moz-user-select: none;
}
```

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Thanks! A dirty workaround indeed... As for now: I removed the input element from the draggable zone, as I didn't achieve the desired effect in all browsers (IE8 was still a problem).

Would you advice against using html5 drag and drop and use JQuery UI drag and drop instead?

Comment: You can find more info by reading: [advantages of html5 drag and drop over jquery ui drag and drop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524543/advantages-of-html-5-drag-and-drop-over-jquery-ui-drag-and-drop) and [html5 vs jquery ui drag and drop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920741/html5-vs-jquery-drag-and-drop). If you need to target a wide range of browsers (legacy browsers also), if you don't want headaches and if you're short on time, I'd recommend using jQuery UI drag and drop.

Answer (score 10):

See Firefox [defect](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1189486).

As an alternative, setting the draggable="false" on input focus event and replacing back to draggable="true" on input blur event works.

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabs79/oa6mr2qa/6/) for an example without any framework.

HTML:

```
<div draggable="true" id="draggableDiv">
    <textarea onfocus="onFocus();" onblur="onBlur();">Inside draggable (FIXED)</textarea>
</div>
```

JS:

```
onFocus= function(e) {
    document.getElementById("draggableDiv").setAttribute("draggable", "false");
}
onBlur= function(e) {
    document.getElementById("draggableDiv").setAttribute("draggable", "true");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave functions on the textarea to set the div draggable only when the mouse is outside the textarea.

I did this because I needed the focus to stay in the edit fields while dragging and dragging itself does not trigger a focus event.

Answer (score 2):

I have also found using onmouseenter and onmouseleave to toggle the draggable attribute works better because it places the cursor in the input box where you actually click. When using onfocus/onblur, the cursor always goes to the start or end of the text even if you click in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

If you are like me and come across this issue, and are using Sortable.js, you can use the `filter` option to specify elements that won't trigger dragging, and thus allow the input to operate normally.

JQuery:

```
$('#my-sortable').sortable({
    filter: ".my-text-input",   // Or whatever class you specify
    preventOnFilter: false      // Allow the input to operate normally
});
```

You can also find this information from the list of Sortable.js options found here:
https://github.com/SortableJS/sortablejs